# Bulk Delete Apps

Tags: applications, delete

On my phone (LG V30+, Android 9) I've noticed when I drag an app from my home screen into the trash, it doesn't delete the app but simply disables it. If I go into settings and find the app, I can fully remove it by pressing uninstall.

(I'm talking about apps I've downloaded, not pre-installed).

When I'm passing through airport security, I have several apps I need to actually delete completely, I can do this by going into settings for each app and choosing uninstall, but this is even more tedious than deleting from the home screen.

Is there any way to bulk delete apps that are disabled.

(ideally without installing a tool to do it, but I'm guessing no such feature exists natively)

Comment: There are tons of apps on play store that do this. Search for " bulk delete apps" and picked up the one with Highest rating (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hrsali.uninstaller). I didn't test any

Comment: As beeshyams wrote. You can find some such apps [in my corresponding list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize#group_4) ordered by rating together with the details on which of them are rather "tracker ridden". The one @beeshyams recommended seems to be a good choice and completely tracker-free.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for checking they out. I just saw last update +rating

Comment: @beeshyams always a good idea to copy-paste the package name to [Exodus](https://reports.exodus-privacy.eu.org/en/analysis/submit/). Easily done, too :D